# Logback: One file with maximum file size

Tags: size, max, logback, logfile

my system support team needs **one** simple **log-file**, with a **maximum size** of 10MB. **Older log-lines** can be **deleted** when the file reaches 10MB. So roll out the oldest lines.

What is a good appender for this?
I have one ***appender***, but this ***still created a second file***, and then ***starts again with an empty new file***. This is not what my support team wants.

*Help is appreciated.*

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="TEST" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME}/test.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/test.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %-5level [%thread] - %mdc{loginName} - [%logger]- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping everything in a single file and constantly adding the most recent while deleting the oldest lines is going to perform really really poorly. I suspect that logback can't be made to do this.

What I suggest is you use the regular size based policy, configure it to stay inside your 10MB limit overall, then just concatenate the files when you grab them.